# In the New 52 Multiverse, are there multiple Apokolips/New Genesis?

Tags: dc, the-new-52

So in Multiversity, it is shown that there is a single Apokolips and New Genesis that exist in the Sphere of the Gods, and that the New Gods are all a singularity, with diluted aspects peppered through the Multiverse.

So does this mean there are multiple Apokolips and New Genesis? Where do these aspects reside? If there are multiple Darkseids running around, then where do they all go?

Have we actually seen the real Darkseid/Apokolips at any point in the New 52 Multiverse?

Comment: I don't think this has been answered yet in the comics, but I hope to be proven wrong by an intrepid responder.

Comment: I'm 99% certain it has been mentioned that there is but one set of New Gods across the New 52 multiverse. And that, for instance, the Darkseid who we saw invade Earth Prime (or whatever it's called) in the initial Justice League story arc is the same Darkseid who invaded Earth 2 in the book of the same name. Since I stopped reading the majority of DC's books quite some time ago, though, I can't really point to a particular source.

Comment: While this is true, it was revealed in The Multiversity that Darkseid and the various New Gods have multiple "emanations" in every world in the Multiverse. That is, the original "true" Darkseid is rebuilding his godhead, and the ones that we have seen in the various comics like Justice League and Earth 2 are simply diluted fragments.

Answer (score 1):

In World's Finest #28 and #29, Intri, member of the Apokolips Pantheon, tells Earth 2 Wonder Woman she is "[a God, a singularity in all the universes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edapr.jpg)" and she is part of "[the True Gods... Unique in all the universes !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu9K7.jpg)"

This means at least members of the Apokolips Pantheon (Darkseid, Desaad, Intri, Steppenwolf and more...) are unique (or at lease they themselves consider being so), and leads to thinking that it would probably be the same for New Genesis' inhabitants.