# Why does Darkseid seem to specifically want Earth 2 Kal-El to be at his side?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, the-new-52

With [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184806/93158), we learn New 52 Darkseid (and the Apokolips Pantheon) are considered unique across the universes (or at lease they themselves consider being so). In [World's Finest #27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BrHc.jpg), we learn from Intri that (most probably) Darkseid plans to raise Earth 2 Kal-El as a Lord of Apokolips.

My question is why is Kal-El the chosen one, considering Intri is at this very moment on a planet full of alive Kryptonians to pick from ?

And, let's say the Kal-El choice is justified (by his future self being freaking Superman, by something Darkseid could have seen in other universes, by him being a natural born Kryptonian, or else ?), why does Intri puts so much effort in trying to capture this *specific* version of Kal-El, as seen in [World's Finest #28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu9K7.jpg) and #29 after that ?

Answer (score 3):

Answering the first part: **Why Kal-El and not other Kryptonians?**

I haven't read World's finest but according to what you have presented and a short overview of the issue, it's obvious that Intri wanted Kal-el and not the other Kryptonians. Reason is ***Kal-el, grew up on Earth and has manifested his powers*** (the other kryptonians are just kryptonians; not super-powered beings).

---

Now, your second question: **Why Kal-El of Earth-2?**

The reason is presented in [Batman/Superman Vol 1. Issue 3](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman/Superman_Vol_1_3).

[image]

Having spent longer under the yellow sun than his Prime Earth counterpart, the Earth-2 Kal-El discovered a greater breadth to his abilities prior to his death (btw, he dies at 29. oops!). See in the snippet above. Prime Earth Superman himself says that he did not develop such levels of control until he was 29 (when Earth-2 Kal-El did it at 22).

So him (Earth-2 Kal-El) being a superior Superman (in a way) could have made Darkseid choose Earth-2 Superman over the Superman of Earth-Prime.

Comment: In the panel I linked from WF #27, Kal-El was still a baby at this time (right before Krypton exploded), so how would Darkseid have known this version of Kal-El would be so powerful in the future ? Besides this, nice answer, I'll read Batman/Superman right away !

Comment: @AntoineAuffray umm, i will have to read *WF* then. If i'm able to spare some time on it, I will definitely add some edits to change the answer to the first part.

Comment: First, isn't the Superman in the full costume the Earth-2 Superman, and the one in the t-shirt the New 52 "Prime Earth" Superman? Second, I read the above panels as the t-shirted Superman not having the foggiest idea what the full-costume Superman is doing, and the full costume Superman explaining it to his younger counterpart as something he may learn to do later in his career. If a later part of the comic has the t-shirted one figuring out how to do cellular reconstruction, then your point may remain.

Answer (score -2):

Well, Kal-El is Superboy Prime.

So, Darkseid would want him specifically due to the fact he's much, much more powerful (and cool) than any other Earth's Superman.

EDIT: As far as I knew, there is only one Kal-El: Superboy Prime. I obviously know there's many versions etc, but I thought his name spelt and arranged in that exact way was Superboy Primes exclusively.

Comment: what does him being cool be of any good to Darkseid?

Comment: I'd also like to see a source for your claim that Earth-2 Kal-El is the most powerful Kal-El.

Comment: @Shreedhar By 'cool', I meant he's aggressive and doesn't give a f@#k.

Comment: The original (pre-Crisis) "Earth-2" Superman's name was Kal-L. To the best of my knowledge, every other non-Elseworlds iteration of Superman has had the Kryptonian name Kal-El. If, by "Earth-Prime Superboy" you're referring to the Superboy seen during Infinite Crisis (the one whose bangs on a wall between universes caused retcons, like Jason Todd's resurrection) - that's not the New 52 "Earth-2" Superman; those are two distinct characters.

Comment: Sorry, I was reviewing the answer, and didn't see the full question. Ignore the Infinite Crisis stuff, it's irrelevant here.